# CSS doesn't apply to class but does to the body element

Tags: html, css

I've experienced this problem multiple times and I haven't found any clear solution yet, so I was hoping you guys could help. I have simple index.php:

```html
<?php
require('libraries/db.php');


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="libraries/style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Phantom 0.1 - Log In</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and style.css in libraries/styles.css:

```css
.container {
    background: url("/libraries/images/background.png") no-repeat fixed center;
}
```

the css works when I try to change, for instance, background color of the body element, but whenever I try to change anything from the .container (or pretty much any other class/id element) the changes won't show.

I've tried it on multiple browsers, cleared the cache and css validator (just in case) but no luck there.

Comment: any console errors? did you include libraries/styles.css in your index.html

Comment: No console errors and yeah, it is linked in the head.

Comment: the only thing i can think is the / in front of the css URL might be trying to hit a root folder. your CSS href is just doing "libraries/style.css" with no leading /

Comment: @Culyx tried that but nothing changed, as I said, when I do changes to body element everything works, just not for any specific elements

Comment: What does dev tools show for the .container DOM object? Does it show any CSS?

Comment: it does not since the css is in different file

Comment: Dev tools should show all CSS affecting a given element, even from different files. So if you don't see it in dev tools, you can check the network tab to see if a call to your CSS file even occured (or the background image)

Comment: Based on the network tab the call should've occured since the style.css file is there (including the bg image)

Comment: But the **style.css** apears in the network tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the problem might be not setting the width/height of the picture. You should also add a ?> on the end in the PHP document in libraries.

**First look**//Sometimes requiring another file using PHP can lead to the  of that file instead. When you run the website localy or online, do inspect element and check if your CSS document line is in the head. https://gyazo.com/fe8f2282e6686d432f75ff994e65c0f7
Also try going into sources when inspecting and check if all the lines are there, there might be a log made if you use Chrome. Do CTRL F5 to load everything over again.

Comment: The file required in <?php section is different from the one I am asking about - I meant style.css in <head>

Comment: Try CTRL + F5 and inspect element to se that everything is there.

Comment: Everything is as it should be

Comment: Copy all your files into this folder please. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1YiBixXDnE_C9zgODdKh2YCtgv0MjzjpM?usp=sharing

Comment: If you want full page change the CSS to this, I think you not setting width/height might be causing you to see it: 
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.container {
  background: url(images/background.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 100vw;
}
https://vidrates.com/fix/index.php //If you want to check online

Comment: No worries. Glad I could help, please mark the thread as solved and mark my response as the correct one :)